# Printf Numerical Right Justify

Tags: c, formatting, printf

I'm trying to format a number that has a value from 0 to 9,999. I would like the 2 most significant digits to always display, i.e.

5000 -> 50
0000 -> 00

If either of the least significant digits are non-zero they should be displayed, i.e.

150 -> 015
101 -> 0101

It can be done with some hackery, but can C's printf do this directly?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your format. If 5000 becomes 50 why does 150 become 015 instead of 15?

Comment: I'm doing cents, and if needed thousandths, and if needed ten-thousandths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly, but working as far as I can tell:

```
printf("%d", value / 1000);
printf("%d", (value % 1000) / 100);
if(value % 100) printf("%d", (value % 100) / 10);
if(value % 10)  printf("%d", value % 10);
```

I'll try to golf it some more:

```
printf("%02d", value / 100);
if(value % 10) printf("%02d", value % 100);
else if(value % 100) printf("%d", (value % 100) / 10);
```

---

```
int hi = value / 100, lo = value % 100;
printf(lo ? "%02d%0*d" : "%02d", hi, 1 + !!(lo % 10), lo % 10 ? lo : lo / 10);
```

Comment: It's not pretty, but it's what I asked for. I implemented it the obvious and more efficient way instead.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use `printf` for this

```
int v = 5000;
if ((v % 100) != 0)
    printf("%04d", v);
else
    printf("%02d", v/100);
```

Comment: Obviously a third case can be added to handle "150" correctly, but is this the only way?

Comment: Yes, you can add as many cases as you'd like. It was only an example how to format numbers with `printf`. I do not think there are better ways to do it in `C`

Answer (score -1):

<strike>`printf("%d", v/(v%100?v%10?100:10:1));`</strike>

Try this:

`printf("%.*d", 4-!(v%100)-!(v%10), v/(v%100?v%10?100:10:1));`

Comment: For `v==1`, should print `"0001"`, not `"1"`